# Assert XML block from a text file with Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, assertions

I have an xml file that contains couple of blocks that have the same parent name, but contain different tags with different values:

```
<Block>
   <tag1>123</tag1>
   <tag2>456</tag2>
   <tag3>789</tag3>
</Block>
<Block>
   <tag1>321</tag1>
   <tag2>654</tag2>
   <tag3>987</tag3>
</Block>
<Block>
   <tag1>111</tag1>
   <tag2>444</tag2>
   <tag3>777</tag3>
</Block>
<Block>
   <tag1>22</tag1>
   <tag2>55</tag2>
   <tag3>88</tag3>
</Block>
```

This file is generated after a specific request based on some inputs and each time should contain specific values.

I want to create a groovy script that automatically verifies the values in the tags of each individual block, but since all these blocks have the same name and I am relatively new at this I can't manage to do it :(  Can you help me with with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic working with XML might look like this

```
File inputFile = new File("path")
def xml = new XmlParser(false, false).parse(inputFile)

xml.Block.each{
    int sum = 0
    sum += it.tag1.toInt()
    sum += it.tag2.toInt()
    sum += it.tag3.toInt()
}
```

You can validate it based on the sum or whatever you need

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast answer. :) I think this should work, but the problem, which I accidentally forgot to mention, is that there are other XML blocks in this file so I also need to define only this particular blocks ... any chance to know how I can do this?

Comment: Everything depends on how many blocks there can be, if only a handful of them, I recommend writing all of them like mentioned above. If some element is optional then you can use syntax xml.element.size() --- 0 does not exist, 1+exists. Please vote my answer up, I have low reputation so I can't vote myself yet :D

Comment: I have voted your answer :) I have tried the code now, but it seems that I am missing something ... `int sum = 0` - here I should give the value that I want to assert or this should correspond to the number of the subsequent block that I want to assert?

Comment: I showed you a way how to list items you desire, There was not a mention of how the validation should look like. In this case it means that after sums you can do if(sum>desiredvalue) println "validation succeeded" else throw new Exception("error, validation failed").
I do not want what you want to validate and how, I just showed you the way how I would approach